# What's difference between expr*, expr? and expr in Python3.6 AST Abstract Grammar?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

In [Python3.6 AST Abstract Grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar), there are `expr*`, `expr?` and `expr` inside. What's difference betweem them? Such as: `expr* targets`, `expr? value` and `expr target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically those suffixes mean the same as in regular expressions:

- `expr` - exactly one instance of the expression
- `expr?`- zero or one instances
- `expr*` - zero or more instances

For example, for the following:

```
FunctionDef(identifier name, arguments args,
            stmt* body, expr* decorator_list, expr? returns)
```

a function definition consists of exactly one name, at least zero statements and asn optional return value (for functions that don't return anything).